# Creating separate pages for list items

Tags: 2013, list, list-view

I’m looking to see whether there is an easier way to automate a task I am currently going to have to end up doing manually.

I have a list which contains all of the companies suppliers, I then have another document library which contains audit information that gets constantly updated. Whenever a new audit report is added to the library a set of information will be included, one of the pieces of information is a look up to the supplier list looking for the supplier name.

What I want to be able to do is have it so that whenever a user clicks on a supplier in the first list it takes them to a standalone page for that supplier and contains a set of different document views which pulls in all the various audit reports from the document library specific to that supplier.

I was just going to do this manually for each supplier, but I’m hopeful there is an easier way to do what I want to do?

I am using SP2013

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a query string filter on a page.  This will filter your views for items pertaining to a supplier.

Add a link field to the supplier list (or use [JSLinks](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013) to format the rendering of a field) that points to the page, along with the query string filter.  I can add visuals if you would like.

Comment: Hi,I think I understand you in principle. What I am a  little unsure of is how to amend the query string filter based off the supplier that has been clicked. Would I have a seperate page for each supplier with the query string amended for each supplier or would I be able to have one page that was dynamic and would change depending on which supplier the user had clicked on?

Comment: A single page.  You should have a filter web part called a [query string filter web part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx) (link is for 2007, but applies to 2013 as well).  Put this on a page, and use it to filter your list view web parts.  Then just link to the page, changing the query string for the different suppliers.  For example: `/sites/mySite/SitePages/SupplierPage.aspx?supplier=AcmeBrick`, and then just change the `supplier=` as needed (or whatever you choose to call the parameter)